# How to parse ISO8601 compliant strings to perl's DateTime object?

Tags: perl, datetime

My final objective is to compare the current date and time with that returned by a TVMaze API that's in ISO8601 format, to determine if a new TV show has been aired.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use DateTime;
my $curmytime = DateTime->now()->format_cldr("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
# Output is: Time now in UTC:2017-07-17T10:44:52+0000
say "Time now in UTC:". $curmytime;
my $strtobeparsed = '2017-04-09T21:00:00-0400';
# Next, parse the string "2017-04-09T21:00:00-0400" to a DateTime object
```

How do I parse the string to a DateTime object?

Comment: That format seems not to be included by default in DateTime::Format::ISO8601. See https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DateTime-Format-ISO8601/lib/DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pod#5.4.1. Easiest way is to roll your own parser.

Comment: It is very odd to have the date and time in *extended* format (with hyphen and colon separators) but the time zone in *basic* format. Are you sure that shouldn't be `-04:00`?

Comment: @Borodin, Yes, `format_cldr("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")` returns it without the colon. I had to remove the colon from the API string to compare both.

Comment: Indeed, that's neither ISO8601 nor RFC3339.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DateTime does not parse dates and times](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#Parsing-Dates). For that, you need to use one of the many modules from the DateTime::Format:: namespace. If there is none available, you can simply use [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime). Give it a [pattern](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime#STRPTIME-PATTERN-TOKENS) and hand it a string, and it will create a DateTime object for you.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => '%FT%T%z');
my $dt = $format->parse_datetime( '2017-04-09T21:00:00-0400' );
```

You can then compare it to another DateTime.

```
print "ok" if $dt < DateTime->now;
```

---

If you wanted to turn that into its own class, that's fairly trivial too.

```
package DateTime::Format::TVMaze;
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
use parent 'DateTime::Format::Strptime';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %params = @_;

    $params{pattern} = '%FT%T%z';

    return $class->SUPER::new(%params);
}
```

Now you can use it like this

```
my $dt = DateTime::Format::TVMaze->new->parse_datetime('2017-04-09T21:00:00-0400');
```

Comment: Thank you. The module POD seems to suggest that it must be first converted to UTC before being able to compare dates.

Comment: @Droidzone that's quite likely.

Comment: @ikegami yes. In that case, there is DateTime::Format::ISO8601 already prepared, but the missing colon is the problem here. Borodin mentioned that in a comment on the question.